# Java - MariaDB Perfoming slow with Hibernate criteria

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

**Environment:**

mariadb-java-client-2.7.0

DB : MariaDB 10.5.7

ojdbc8 - Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 JDBC 4.0

DB : Oracle Database 11g

Hibernate 4.3.8

**Code :**

```
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria fetchCriteria = session.createCriteria("Student");
        
        Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
            Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
            conjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("RollNumber", i+""));
            disjunction.add(conjunction);
        }
        
        fetchCriteria.add(disjunction);
          long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List  resultList = fetchCriteria.setFirstResult(0).setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
         long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
         System.out.println("Time took :"+(end1-start1) +"ms");
```

**Issue**

1. If i run above code with Hibernate 4.3.8 + Oracle 8 it taking less than 5000 milliseconds.
2. If i run above code with Hibernate 4.3.8  +mariadb-java-client-2.7.0 it taking more than 40,000 milliseconds.

**Extra Configuration :**
I have set hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size to 100 in hibernate.cfg.xml
along with jdbc URL ,username and password.

**Findings:**

1. The query generated in both cases are same and if i execute those
   query with SQL Client it takes 10-11 seconds for ORACLE and 41-42 seconds for MariaDB.
2. The query which is generated by both database if i invoke using JDBC
   program (both for ORACLE and MariaDB) it is taking approx 600 milliseconds

**Note:** Both tables (Oracle and MariaDB) have 15,000 records.

Can anyone help me why MariaDB is taking time?
or some extra settings are required to improve the MariaDB performance.
I have tried defaultFetchSize which is mentioned in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/ but no luck.

**SQL Query Generated by the databases:**

```
select  this_.rollNo as RollNo1_0_0_, this_.VersionID as Version2_0_0_,
        this_.Name as Name3_0_0_, this_.dept as dept4_0_0_,
        this_.favSubj as favSubj5_0_0_,
        this_.ID as ID33_0_0_
    from  Student this_
    where  ((this_.ID='1')
              or  (this_.ID='2')
              or  (this_.ID='3')
              or  ....
              or  (this_.ID='10000')
```

**MariaDB DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `RollNo` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,
  `VersionID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) COLLATE ucs2_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept` varchar(100) COLLATE ucs2_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `favSubj` varchar(100) COLLATE ucs2_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` varchar(100) COLLATE ucs2_bin DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`RollNo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_student` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20258138 DEFAULT CHARSET=ucs2 COLLATE=ucs2_bin
```

**Oracle DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  RollNo NUMBER(19,0), 
  VersionID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
  Name VARCHAR2(100),
  dept  VARCHAR2(100),
  favSubj VARCHAR2(100),
  ID VARCHAR2(100), 
  PRIMARY KEY ("RollNo"),
  CONSTRAINT "UK_student" UNIQUE ("ID")
)
```

**MariaDB explain select query output**

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | this_ | range | UK_Student | UK_Student | 203 | NULL | 10000 | Using index condition |

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and the table definitions.

Comment: Ask your DBA about this. You are probably missing an index in MariaDB that you have in Oracle.

Comment: @RickJames added table definition and generated SQL.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov index is proper.

Comment: I guess Oracle is just better at optimising/executing this query than MariaDB. Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan MariaDB generates and compare that to the query plan of Oracle. It also depends on the machine the database is running on.

Comment: @RickJames, I have added MariaDB query plan.

Comment: This is a case where it should _not_ use the index.  Change from `VARCHAR` to `INT`!

Comment: After changing VARCHAR to INT it is taking 25-27 seconds.

Comment: @RickJames If I checked Query profile in HeidiSQL out of 40 seconds, 34 seconds are going on Statistics. Any way to avoid Statistics ?

Comment: @Developer - In my opinion, "Profile" (which is where 'Statistics' is coming from) is useless.  This will give some numbers that could help get insight into what MariaDB is doing:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts .

Answer (score 0):

An `OR` with 10K items takes a long time to parse.  Faster would be an `IN`:

```
 where  this_.ID IN ('1', '2', ..., '10000')
```

However, even that is likely to take a long time to run.

In the case of MariaDB, I think the Optimizer will say

- Oh, that's too many items for me to look up each one, so
- I will, instead, simply scan the table, checking each row for an `ID` in that list (using some kind of efficient lookup in the 10K-long list).

However, if there are 20M rows in the table, that will take a long time.

Can you provide the query plan (EXPLAIN) so we can confirm what I am hypothecating?

This seems logical and faster, but *will not* work correctly:

```
 where  this_.ID BETWEEN '1' AND '10000'
```

because it is a VARCHAR!!

**Performance** -- Make `id` an `INT`, *not* a `VARCHAR`!